# Does one year experience count for partner skill criteria in Australia PR process

Tags: australia, pr

I know if my spouse is an applicant for the PR visa and meets age, English and skill criteria, I can get 10 points for it. She meets the age and has competent English score. So I will get 5 points for it.

But she has just one year of work experience. Does this experience count for Skill criteria?

She studied a bachelors degree in computer science and having one year of experience and still working. If she gets accessed(ACS), will I get additional 5 points for her experience?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention skill criteria but not the actual visa subclass I'm going to assume the 189 subclass. Note that this is not intended to be visa advice, you must do your own research or speak to a qualified professional.

The "Partner skills" section of the [189 visa points table](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/skilled-independent-189/points-table) says that to meet the skill criteria they, among other things, must have had at the time of invitation

> a suitable skills assessment from the relevant assessing authority for their nominated skilled occupation, and the assessment wasn’t for a Subclass 485 visa

Probably not what you were hoping to hear but it seems you need to ask the assessing authority.